# Can't figure out how to clear this exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

While running the code below I keep getting a null pointer exception can anyone help?  It is a method for pulling a random word from a txt document for a word game.  While I am running it in JCreator it works perfectly but as soon as I try to open it in a browser it stops working.  Thanks.

```
     public String getaword()
{

     try
     {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.txt"));
        String str=null;
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
            while((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lines.add(str);
                words = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);
            }
     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
   Random r = new Random();
   int num;
   num = new Integer (r.nextInt(words.length));  
   return words[num];
}
```

Comment: words is declared outside of this method.  I can edit it for the whole code if necessary its not too long.

Comment: @user3261079 `words` was declared **but not initialized** if the `sample.txt` file not found or empty content. therefore  `words.length` give you `NullPointerException`

Comment: @user3261079 changing `r.nextInt(words.length)` to something like `r.nextInt(5)` will clear the `NPE`. but of course, `num` value will become meaningless

Comment: First, post the stack trace! Next, explain what you mean by _"as soon as I try to open it in a browser"_ -- is this a Java applet?